# Cant get my elif functions right

Tags: python-3.x

```
menu_item =     MainMenu = ["Display Team Roster", "Add Member", "Remove Member", "Edit Member", "Exit Program"]
while menu_item != 9:
    print("Welcome to the Team Manager!")
    print("1. Display Team Roster.")
    print("2. Add Member.")
    print("3. Remove Member.")
    print("4. Edit Member")
    print("9. Exit Program.")
menu_item = int(input("Selection:"))
elifmenu_item == 1
print(current)
current = 0
while len(MainMenu) > 0:
    current < len(MainMenu)
print(current, ".", MainMenu[current])
current = current + 1
elifmenu_item == 2
name = input("Enter new member's name:")
MainMenu.append(name)
elifmenu_item == 3
del_name = input("Enter member name to be removed:")
del_name in MainMenu
item_number = MainMenu.index(del_name)
del MainMenu[1]
elifmenu_item == 4
old_name = input("Enter the name of the member you want to edit:")
old_name in MainMenu
item_number = MainMenu.index(old_name)
new_name = input("Enter the new name of the member:")
MainMenu[1] = new_name
else:
print("Goodbye")
```

Write a modularized program that will utilize a main menu to control the program’s functions and a list to store the members of your team. The following functions that your program needs to include:
•Print the current member list.
•Add a new member.
•Remove a member.
•Modify an existing member.
•Exit the program

Answer (score 0):

`elif` is not a function, it is language element just like `while`, `if`.

It has to be used together with `if` (just like `else`), example:

```
if a == '1':
    print('1')
elif a == '2':
    print('2')
else:
   print('other')
```

In your case you have `elifmenu_item == 1` which is wrong, you should have a space after `elif` and you should start with an `if`, only subsequent cases use `elif`.